# Python: Constructor Set()

Tags: python, set

I was looking at the python documentation about set(), but I'm still trying to understand why does this function deletes repeated characters in a string, for example:

```
set("apple")
```

returns `{"a","p","l","e"}`.
Is it a special property of sets?

Comment: That is the *definition* of sets. They contain each item only once.

Comment: Sets are unordered collections of unique objects. The set constructor accepts an iterable of objects. You passed it a string, which is an iterable of strings of the individual characters in the string. So, `s = 'abc'` and `list(s)` will give you `['a','b','c']`

Comment: Is your question why the result is not a set containing the single string `"apple"`, but the set of all the individual letters?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the first sentence of the `set` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) (emphasis added):

> A set object is an unordered collection of **distinct** hashable objects.

"distinct" can be interpreted here to mean "unique" or "non-repeating" objects; as the example use cases note:

> Common uses include membership testing, **removing duplicates from a sequence**, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

Because `str` are iterables of their own letters, `set("apple")` is essentially a faster equivalent to `set(["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"])`, which causes the duplicated letters to be removed. If you'd wanted a `set` with an initial entry of `"apple"`, you'd use `{"apple"}` (set literal) or `set(("apple",))`/`set(["apple"])` (set constructor applied to `tuple` or `list` of values to include). This is a general property of `str`, not specific to `set` cases; `list("apple")` would produce `["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]` for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

If an optional iterable parameter is supplied to set(), it updates the set with elements obtained from iteration. That is from the docs.

```
set('apple')
{'a', 'p', 'l', 'e'}
set(('a','p','p','l','e'))
{'a', 'p', 'l', 'e'}
set(['a','p','p','l','e'])
{'a', 'p', 'l', 'e'}
```

A set only contains unique elements. When you pass it an iterable, ie. string, tuple, list - It creates a set, iterating over the passed in object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sets contain unique elements and are much faster for comparisons like checking if an item exists than lists for example. As well as having lots of other nice properties.

so another example would be

```
set([1,1,1,2,3])
```

returns

```
{1,2,3}
```

the unique items.

One thing to note is that sets are not ordered like lists, which has both positives and negatives

Answer (score 0):

`set()` accepts an iterable in this case `apple` is treated as one, yielding 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e' which are then added to the set and because sets only contain unique elements you end up with `{"a","p","l","e"}`.